# Instrumentation sendPointerSync will not invoke hover events

Tags: android, hover, mouse, instrumentation, motionevent

If I use the Instrumentation class in Android to send mouse movements like so:

```
mInstrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE, x, y, 0));
```

As the pointer moves across GUI objects they do not receive "hover" events.

Anyone know why?

Plugging in a USB mouse does generate hover events.